# Excel formatting issue - columns shrinked

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, citrix

Last night I have saved my work in a excel file and when I opened the file in morning, the formatting was lost. Columns in all the sheets are shrunk (see below image). I had accessed this workbook from citrix as it was on my office server and the last time I saved all was perfect. What can be the reason for this issue?

[image]

[image]

Comment: it seems like you accidentally applied the column width (all narrow columns were selected and you dragged them to change width)

Comment: Not sure we will be able to tell you the cause of it. Were you able to fix it?

Comment: Are any of those shrunk columns empty? Are all the ones that aren't empty the same size in pixels? What about the empty ones?

Comment: @MátéJuhász It can't happen to all the sheets.

Comment: @Raystafarian  Columns to the right are empty and have shrunk and are of same size. I have added a image.

Comment: Most likely some commands in citrix got weird or there was a hiccup that selected all sheets, then all cells and then, as @MátéJuhász said, somehow a click and drag occurred to that width

Comment: For the record, ctrl+shft+pgdn, if stuck, will select all sheets.

Comment: @Raystafarian It can be the reason, but I feel there is remote possibility for it as I was careful and I am sure that I have saved it properly.

Comment: Maybe someone else did it? Remember that when you connect through citrix, the viewing resolution is distorted, so who knows what it thinks server-side. edit [check here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1573349/excel-the-incredible-shrinking-and-expanding-controls) for a different example.